# Spring boot - second entity update overrides changes made by the first one

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two http requests that come almost at the same time to my spring boot server and both of them should update the same entity in the database.
First request updates progress of the task that the client is executing:

```
fun updateProgress(workUnitId: Int, progress: Double): HttpResponse<Boolean> {
    val optionalWorkUnit = workUnitDAO.findById(workUnitId)
    return if (optionalWorkUnit.isPresent) {
        val workUnit = optionalWorkUnit.get()
        workUnit.progress = progress
        workUnitDAO.save(workUnit)
        logger.info("updating progress ${workUnit.progress}... ${workUnit.status}")
        HttpResponse(true)
    } else {
        HttpResponse(false)
    }
}
```

And the second one records result returned by the processing client:

```
fun recordResult(workUnitId: Int, result: String): HttpResponse<Boolean> {
    val optionalWorkUnit = workUnitDAO.findById(workUnitId)
    return if (optionalWorkUnit.isPresent) {
        val workUnit = optionalWorkUnit.get()
        workUnit.result = result
        workUnit.finishDate = Date()
        workUnit.status = Status.FINISHED
        workUnit.progress = 2.0 // changed from 1.0 to 2.0 to help noticing changes in the db
        workUnitDAO.save(workUnit)
        logger.info("result recorder ${workUnit.status}")
        HttpResponse(true)
    } else {
        HttpResponse(false)
    }
}
```

The problem is that if the first request to be processed is recording result then the next that updates progress reads entity as it has never been changed by the first request(status saved by the first one is FINISHED but the second one reads IN_PROGRESS):

```
2020-04-29 18:30:15.595  INFO 16368 --- [nio-8082-exec-2] p.p.server.service.WorkUnitService       : result recorder FINISHED
2020-04-29 18:30:15.595  INFO 16368 --- [nio-8082-exec-3] p.p.server.service.WorkUnitService       : updating progress 1.0... IN_PROGRESS
```

My service is annotated with @Transactional

```
@Service
@Transactional
class WorkUnitService {
```

DAO:

```
interface WorkUnitDAO : JpaRepository<WorkUnit, Int> {
```

I have tried changing repository save() mathods to saveAndFlush() but it didn't help.

Removing entity change from updateProgress method prevents this from happening (despite the fact that the entity is still saved):

```
fun updateProgress(workUnitId: Int, progress: Double): HttpResponse<Boolean> {
    val optionalWorkUnit = workUnitDAO.findById(workUnitId)
    return if (optionalWorkUnit.isPresent) {
        val workUnit = optionalWorkUnit.get()
        //workUnit.progress = progress //removing this stops overwritting values from recordResult
        workUnitDAO.save(workUnit)
        logger.info("updating progress ${workUnit.progress}... ${workUnit.status}")
        HttpResponse(true)
    } else {
        HttpResponse(false)
    }
}
```

Settings:

```
spring:
 datasource:
  url: jdbc:mysql://*******:9099/master?useUnicode=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

I have tried annotatting everything with @Transactional, tried CrudRepository nothing helped.

Spring boot version: 2.2.4.RELEASE

I would like those method not to override each other. I have been stuck with this for a few hours already.

It there something I missed or did wrong?

Comment: Use pessimistic locking or implement concurrent version control (i.e. versioning on your entity).

Comment: I agree with what @M.Deinum said. If you update independent fields you could also consider `@DynamicUpdate`

Comment: I'm not talking about individual field updates I'm talking about implementing locking (pessimistic or optimistic).

Comment: After @M.Deinum comment I changed my repository method to `@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    override fun findById(id: Int): Optional<WorkUnit>` and I got the expected behaviour. I am not sure if this is the right kind of locking for me but I will have to give it more reading as I didn't know about this kind of feature before.